# WooCommerce ACF Display custom meta data on Cart and Checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, product

I would like to show the value of my custom field created with [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin, at the same time in WooCommerce cart and checkout pages.

I'm using the code below in the **`functions.php`** page of my theme, which displays only in the single page of the product:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_custom_field', 0 );

function add_custom_field() {
    global $post;

  echo "<div class='produto-informacoes-complementares'>";
  echo get_field( 'info_complementar', $product_id, true );
  echo "</div>";

    return true;
}
```

Thank you all in advanced for all the help given and excuse my english.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't test this on your web shop, so I am not completely sure:

Displaying custom field value in single product page *(your function)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_product_custom_field', 0 );

function add_product_custom_field() {
    global $product;

    if ( $info_complementar = get_field( 'info_complementar', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        echo '<div class="produto-informacoes-complementares">' . $info_complementar . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Storing this custom field into cart and session:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_my_custom_product_field', 10, 2 );

function save_my_custom_product_field( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( $info_complementar = get_field( 'info_complementar', $product_id ) ) 
    {
        $cart_item_data['info_complementar'] = $info_complementar;

        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Render meta on cart and checkout:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

function render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $custom_items = array();

    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
        $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item['info_complementar'] ) ) {
        $custom_items[] = array( 
            'name' => __("Info complementar"), 
            'value' => $cart_item['info_complementar'] 
        );
    }
    return $custom_items;
}
```

There were some mistakes in the 2 last hooks, making trouble… Now it should work.

---

**Addition:**

Display ACF value in order detail page after order table

```
add_action ('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'action_order_details_after_order_table', 20 );

function action_order_details_after_order_table($order) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( $info_complementar = get_field('info_complementar', $item->get_product_id())) {
            printf('<p class="info-complementar">%s: %s<p>', __("Info complementar"), $info_complementar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loic is this an old hook names?

Comment: @Wed The hooks used are still working on last Woocommerce version.