# Showing advanced custom fields on Woocommerce order page (front and admin) and emails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

My goal is to add an advanced custom field for WooCommerce subscriptions, editable on subscription edit pages, and display the custom field value on customer subscription page. It would be great to display it also in the WooCommerce email notifications.

I see that my question has been answered in [Display advanced custom fields value in Woocommerce order details and all emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58675101/display-advanced-custom-fields-value-in-woocommerce-order-details-and-all-emails/66083512#66083512) thread, but apparently the answer has been removed.

I hope someone can help out.

Comment: The deleted answer was plagiarized from this existing answer: [WooCommerce ACF Display custom metadata on Cart and Checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076161/woocommerce-acf-display-custom-meta-data-on-cart-and-checkout-page/38077098#38077098), and the question is not really similar to yours. So maybe better search [in those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advanced-custom-fields+orders) then try to make your own code… If you have some issue with your code attempt, you can ask a new question, providing that code with all related details in a clear way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It was quite challenging, but eventually got it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code shows the ACF repeater value for a repeater sub field on the subscription page in WooCommerce My Account page. Under the subscription details.

```php
<?php

/**
 * Show ACF custom repeater field on subscription page [while]
 */
// Display XNumbers on subcription
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_details_table', 'display_acf_on_subcriptions', 20);
    function display_acf_on_subcriptions( $subscription ) { ?>

<h2>ACF Custom Repeater XNumbers:</h2>
<?php if( have_rows('acf_xnumbers_repeater', $subscription->id) ): ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>XNumbers</th>
        </tr>
    <?php while ( have_rows('acf_xnumbers_repeater', $subscription->id) ) : the_row();
        $sub_value = get_sub_field('XNumbers'); ?>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <?php echo "$sub_value"; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </table>
<br/>
 <?php else : ?>
    <p> There are no XNumbers found.</p>
    <br/>
 <?php endif;

}
```

Comment: For viewing the ACF custom repeater field on the admin subscription edit page, just enable it from the ACF plugin menu under tab 'presentation'.